# codeigniter: modify value in view from controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

I am trying to modified value from controller to view. I would like to achieve that when a user is signing up, and submited, I can return feedback from model to controller to view.

my view: main_view

```
   <?php include('header.php'); ?>
     <?php echo $sign_up_results ?> 

     <?php include('forms/forms.php'); ?>
   <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

my controller

```
   function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $template = $this->load->View('main_view');
}   

function form_sign_up_controller(){
    $this->load->model("form_sign_up"); 
    $database_insert_results = $this->form_sign_up->insert_user_detail_into_db();
    $data['sign_up_results']=$database_insert_results;
    $template = $this->load->View('main', $data);
}
```

The problem is when the view is loaded, the value "$sign_up_results" is not yet defined. Is there anyway that I can define the value and then change the value according to the results return from model to controller.

Answer (score 1):

just use is set to check if the parameter is defined or not

`<?php if(isset($sign_up_results)) echo $sign_up_results ?>`

Comment: the error is now gone. But since the page does not refresh, or reload, the value is still not going to come up.

Comment: i don't understand why the page doesn't refresh or reload.. can u tell me more about the architecture of you project